# ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, npm, ionic-framework

Solution:

1. Remove platform with `ionic platform rm android`
2. change permission `chmod 777 /path/to/update-notifier-cordova.json`
3. add platform with `ionic platform add android`

It's probably due to another project I created that would cause the permission change. I think chaning the permission (see step #2) should be enough.

Original post:
When running `ionic run android` I got this error message:

> ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try
>   setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your
>   'PATH'. Try update your 'PATH' to include path to valid SDK directory.

I set the environment variable in the bashrc file:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/think/dev/android-sdk-linux
export PATH=$PATH:/home/think/dev/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

It used to work a few hours before and I can't remember to change anything in the settings or whatever. :/

I installed npm, cordova, inonic again, but I still got this error.

I'm using ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.profile` is ignored if if there's `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` in your home, as a result of `~/.profile` being ignored, `~/.bashrc` isn't sourced.

Check for either `~/.bash_profile` or `~/.bash_login` present in your home, and take a new terminal, will help you.

Comment: I do have a .bash_profile file. What should I do with it? Delete it? I opened it and it was empty.

Comment: Delete it if it present in home (it'll be hidden), take new terminal window and try

Comment: Ok, but how come I suddenly get this file?

Comment: I deleted it. Tried to run and got This error message: Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/think/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

I changed the permission with chmod 744 . I tried to run it with "sudo". And I still got the same error message in the OP:ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually.

Comment: restore `~/.bash_profile` and add `source ~/.profile`  and 
`source ~/.bashrc`  to it. and try

Comment: I created in HOME a file ".bash_profile". in that file I wrote in the 1st line: "source ~/.profile". In the 2nd line: "source ~/.bashrc" to it. 
I then executed ionic build android and ionic run android. I would always get the same error:
Error: EACCES: permission denied, open '/home/think/.config/configstore/update-notifier-cordova.json'
You don't have access to this file.

Comment: Have you tried in new terminal?, could you please check `update-notifier-cordova.json` permission manually?

Comment: Yes, I opened a new terminal. What do you mean with "check update-notifier-cordova.json"? Should I change the permission to that file with  "chmod 744"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102180/discussion-between-biju-parvathy-and-thadeuszlay).