# ANDROID_HOME environment variable not saving

Tags: android, variables, meteor, sdk, environment

I am trying to begin development of an android app using meteor however I am running into this error:

"Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable"

This seems to be a common problem and has received mixed attention as in these other 3 questions.

1. [Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36249294/error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable)
2. [ERROR: Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35120248/error-error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable)
3. [Android Error: Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41664253/android-error-failed-to-find-android-home-environment-variable)

But doesn't seem to have an answer in any of them. In my case it seems that the variable is not saving after restarting the shell.

Following the instruction from these two links:

https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/running-on-mobile
https://guide.meteor.com/mobile.html#installing-prerequisites

I am stuck on the "meteor run android" command. In the terminal it returns:

```
Status of the individual requirements:        
✓ Java JDK                                    
✗ Android SDK: 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable is set to non-existent path:
  /home/eru/Library/Android/sdk
  Try update it manually to point to valid SDK directory.
✗ Android target: Android SDK not found. Make sure that it is installed. If it
  is not at the default location, set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.
✗ Gradle: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to
  update your Android SDK.
  Looked here: /home/eru/Library/Android/sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

When I run:

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

I get nothing. and when I run:

```
echo $PATH
```

I get a bunch of stuff that does include:

```
$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

So I checked the "env" command and ANDROID_HOME wasn't present but $PATH does have what is required for the SDK.

I ran the export commands again, copied and pasted from the instructions. "echo $ANDROID_HOME" now returns the correct directory and is present when I run "env".

Interestingly "source ~/.bash_profile" doesn't exist so to restart the shell I just closed all my terminals and tried "echo" again. ANDROID_HOME is once again non-existent.

Why was my $PATH env variable saved but not $ANDROID_HOME?

Comment: Have you tried editing your `.bash_profile` file directly?

Comment: I don't seem to have one. I have a dot.bash_profile @/usr/share/doc/adduser/examples/adduser.local.conf.examples/skel

Comment: I just created one and added the two export commands but I'm getting the same effect where $ANDROID_HOME always returns as nonexistent after "echo", "env", or "meteor run android".

Comment: Strange. Try reloading it with `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: FWIW, here's the `~/.bash_profile` that I use on my mac that works for me: https://gist.github.com/dmnugent80/fea66eb354ba1b40652c846c2d1d0f7a

Comment: I made the file and

1. added the 2 required export commands
2. added your whole file that you linked (despite using linux)

Neither worked

Comment: You'll need to modify the path in order to match where the sdk lives on your file system.... Also, you don't need the NDK stuff or the ruby stuff.